# Emacs and CWB under Windows

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I'm trying to use the Edinburgh Concurrency Workbench (http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/perdita/cwb/) with Emacs under Windows. I have placed the file cwb.el under C:\emacs\emacs-22.3\emacs-stuff. My .emacs file is located at C:\emacs and has the following content:

```
(setq load-path             ; Look in my own library first.
      (cons (expand-file-name "C:\emacs\emacs-22.3\emacsstuff")
        load-path))
(autoload 'cwb "cwb" "Run a CWB process." t)
(autoload 'cwb-file-mode "cwb" "Major mode for editing CWB source." t)
(add-hook 'cwb-load-hook
  (function
   (lambda ()
 (setq cwb-program-name "cwb7")))) ;; only necessary if your v7 isn't
                                       ;; called cwb
```

Yet, when I enter "M-x cwb", I get "Cannot open load file: cwb".

I tried to follow the instruction here: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/perdita/cwb/doc/emacs.html.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Emacs Lisp strings, backslash is an escape character, similar to C, so `"C:\emacs\emacs-22.3\emacsstuff"` ends up being `"C:^[macs^[macs-22.3^[macsstuff"`. (You can try it with either <kbd>M-:</kbd> or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ielm`.)

You can either write the path with forward slashes instead (`"C:/emacs/emacs-22.3/emacsstuff"`) or use double backslashes (`"C:\\emacs\\emacs-22.3\\emacsstuff"`).